# Incorrect setting in emails server that send emails for other stack's sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, email-notification, dns

I believe that DNS settings (at least for superuser.com) is incorrect.

DNS's `TXT` record for `SPF` on superuser.com is (as of Jule 18, 2018):

```
superuser.com.          300     IN      TXT     "v=spf1 -all"
```

that tells all email servers in the world that domain `superuser.com` - don't sent emails and asking receiving servers to reject any emails that comes as xxx@superuser.com, but in fact emails sent via `mx-out.stackexchange.com` from user:
do-not-reply@superuser.com

There also no `MX` record for superuser.com that authorize email server that sends emails for domain superuser.com

So, as result receiving email server reject emails that sent kinda from superuser.com: (I replaced real recipient's email address for obvious reason)

```
policyd-spf[91067]: None; identity=helo; client-ip=198.252.206.125; helo=mx-out.stackexchange.com; envelope-from=do-not-reply@superuser.com; receiver=user@example.com
policyd-spf[91067]: Fail; identity=mailfrom; client-ip=198.252.206.125; helo=mx-out.stackexchange.com; envelope-from=do-not-reply@superuser.com; receiver=user@example.com
postfix/smtpd[90542]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mx-out.stackexchange.com[198.252.206.125]: 550 5.7.1 <user@example.com>: Recipient address rejected: Message rejected due to: SPF fail - not authorized. Please see http://www.openspf.org/Why?s=mfrom;id=do-not-reply@superuser.com;ip=198.252.206.125;r=user@example.com; from=<do-not-reply@superuser.com> to=<user@example.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mx-out.stackexchange.com>
```

So, some1 @stackexchange who is responsible for email servers need to read this:

http://www.openspf.org/Why?s=mfrom;id=do-not-reply@superuser.com;ip=198.252.206.125;r=user@example.com

As a suggestion - all stackexchange's sites need to authorize mx-out.stackexchange.com as their primary MTA by adding to DNS MX record that point to mx-out.stackexchange.com and adjust SPF record that tells other servers in the world that mx-out.stackexchange.com or IP(s) of your MTA are only responsible to send emails for all forums.

Or at least set (I hope as temporary fix)

```
superuser.com.          300     IN      TXT     "v=spf1 ~all"
```

so emails would be tagged on receiving side as SPF rule violation but at least would be passed to recipient instead of telling other servers in the world to reject emails that comes from xxxx@superuser.com.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the heads up. We shouldn't have been sending emails from `@superuser.com` at all. Everything is now (well as of yesterday) sent from `@stackoverflow.email` which has a correctly configured DMARC policy.

Comment: And now all of a sudden, gmail is complaining that mail that I redirect to them from stackoverflow.email is violating DMARC -- I'm guessing this change is why.  So I changed my global email setting to go straight to gmail, but all my alerts are still coming via the redirection and bouncing.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @FredDouglis which alerts are you referring to?

Comment: Posts matching my filters

Comment: In addition, it's worth noting that the "newsletters" are going to the new address, while the "posts matching your filter" emails are going to the old one.

Comment: @FredDouglis urgh, yes you've noticed the one area we haven't fully ported yet. It's on the radar just not for a little while longer yet

Comment: Aha.  OK, I'll just miss the alerts in the meantime... thanks.

Comment: Dean, on thing not to “port” and another not to take an email update and apply it. Isn’t that straightforward? And if not, could you do a one-off database update to reconcile?